# gnome panels disappear after changing display resolution

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi on a Win-XP Dell laptop.  Worked great, until I changed the display resolution to match the native resolution of an external monitor.  After doing so, the gnome panels (the top and bottom bars) have disappeared.  The gnome-panel process is still running, but I can't see the panels.  When I kill the process it restarts immediately but nothing changes.  Alt+F1 and Alt+F2 don't do anything in this state, so it's kind of useless.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

External/secondary monitors don't show the GNOME panels... It might be possible that your monitor is set as secondary.

Comment: It is set as secondary; that seemed to be the only way to get the full resolution.  Probably everything is visible on the primary (laptop) monitor; I'll confirm that.

I don't really want to use both monitors, just one or the other.  But I'd like the full 1920x1200 resolution on the external monitor when the laptop cover is closed.  Maybe this needs to be a separate question, but in case there's any insight out there while this is still fresh, I'm adding the question here.  When the monitors share the same display, the full resolution is not available.  Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Confirmed.  Turned off the laptop monitor (in the display settings) and now it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDavis You're welcome! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Originally I thought this is a bug and searched for solutions. Most say:

- `gconftool`
- `rm -rf .gconf`
- `pkill gnome-panel`

However none of them worked.

I launched gnome-display-properties, found there are two monitors and turned off *Laptop Monitor*. The taskbars show up now!